# Is there a way for mongoexport tool to export guids in .net encoding?

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

Is there a way for mongoexport tool to export guids in **.net encoding** instead of raw encoding?

Here is the export I am running:

```
mongoexport --db sandbox --collection guidtest --type csv --out testguid.csv --limit 10 --fields "_id"
```

Document:

```
{ "_id" : BinData(3, "AAE8ifyz4Uqi0afyAN6kYw==") }
```

Expected result:

```
893C0100B3FC4AE1A2D1A7F200DEA463
```

Actual result:

```
00013C89FCB3E14AA2D1A7F200DEA463
```

Comment: `mongoexport` (as at 4.0) doesn't have any special awareness of .NET encoding so I expect you may have write your own export script. However, for clarity please edit your question to include a MongoDB document with an example of the original GUID format and the desired .NET encoding.

Comment: Thanks @Stennie. Where do I go to upvote that feature?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be an existing feature request for this, but you could raise one in the TOOLS project in the MongoDB Jira issue tracker: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS. The shortest path to a fix would be writing your own CSV export script.

Comment: Note: it looks like the underlying issue is that the .NET framework's  [Guid.ToByteArray()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.tobytearray?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns results in a different order from the string representation of a Guid: `The order of the beginning four-byte group and the next two two-byte groups is reversed, whereas the order of the last two-byte group and the closing six-byte group is the same.`